# In C++ How to use an atribute from another class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

So I've got two different classes in C++,

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
    public:
        ...
    private:

        static const int MAX = 52;

        int a_array[MAX];

};

#endif // A_H
```

And I'd like to use that array into another class... But I was wondering if I can't just return an array, how should I do it? Am I forced to create another array in the class B and copy it?

THis would be the second class...

```
#include "A.h"
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

class B
{
    public:
        ...
        void createNewDeck("here would be the array, or the object I'd like to input to use the array inside");
    private:

        static const int min = 5;


        int a_array[min]

};

#endif // B_H
```

EDIT: I want them to be different, I'd like to have a B method that works with the A class array. I would have a B method that takes some values from that array; something like this so you guys can get my idea.

```
void B::createNewDeck(const A &a){
    a_array[0] = a.a_array[5];
    a_array[3] = a.a_array[48];
}
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: inheritance ? or maybe you want instances of A and B to be different (in this case pass A by reference and make a geter function for the array)

Comment: @Raxvan I just edited so you can get to understand what I want my two classes to do!

Comment: The solution to part of your problem is to implement `int & operator[](int index){return a_array[index]}`. Then you can `a_array[0] = a[5];`. The rest of your problem I'm not quite understanding.

Comment: You can declare the `createNewDecka` function a `friend` of class `A`.

Comment: You should probably better use a `std::vector<int> a_array;` and provide a function that returns a reference of `a_array`.

Answer (score 1):

The array is just a pointer to a piece of data.  But you need to be very clear on what you want.  Do you want to copy the data and have a separate copy to play with?  Or do you want the second class to have full access to the original?

You can return the pointer in a function or make the member variable accessible as either public or via a friend.

Comment: I've just edited the post! But I'd like to keep my class A array to remain private, but still get to get the values from the A array.

Comment: _@JoshK_ The problem with returning a pointer is, that the size information is lost.

Comment: Agreed, but if he knows what he is accessing then he is fine.  I think the real problem here is that are too many possible ways to do it.  The requirement needs to be refined a bit more.

Comment: Other problem with returning a pointer is it wrecks the encapsulation. You can do anything you want with a pointer, so that private is now public in all but name. Returning a pointer to const can help, but still allows some stupid behaviour.

Comment: Agreed with that too.  But the op isn't asking about "the right way" to do it.  Or the more elegant way.  IMHO for a kid learning C++ he needs at first to figure out that the array is just a pointer , the pointer can be passed around, the data isn't coppied in any way, etc.  Then he can move on to all kinds of idioms including stl vectors...

Answer (score 0):

```
create a method in public int Array(int index) and return the value to your desired

like:


class B
{
    public:

        void createNewDeck("here would be the array, or the object I'd like to input to use the array inside");
    private:

        static const int min = 5;


        int a_array[min]

// Method to return value outside

public:
        int Array(int Index)
{
  return Index>min ?-1:a_array[Index-1];
}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to make `B` a friend of `A`. That way `B` will have access to `A`'s `private` member.

```
class B; // forward declare B to make it visible in A's scope. Important

class A
{
    private:
        static const int MAX = 52;

        int a_array[MAX];

        friend class B; // !!
        //friend B; // if you have C++11
};
```

Comment: Oh! I'm doing this for academy purposes, and we're supposed to implement only what we've "learned", so I'm basically not allowed to use that. We haven't done anything with friends this year! Even though I will look some info about friends for self-knowledge!